# How to remove "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration" from Thunderbird?

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird

I removed Unity from my system (Ubuntu 13.04), however, there is a remaining file located in Thunderbird Extensions, which is "Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration". I searched for the file in Synaptic, but I didn't find it.

My question is: What is the name of the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This extension is included in Thunderbird's package itself. You would need to run:

`sudo rm /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi`

This will remove the extension's installer. When you do so it should (in theory) allow you to remove it from your Thunderbird profile.

Comment: On my system the path is `/usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/`. Running `sudo rm /usr/lib/thunderbird-addons/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi` did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dennis my apologies I copied from the wrong package (I use both the Daily builds and the stable builds on this system).

Comment: No problem, you helped me anyway.

Comment: Does someone distribute a version of the thunderbird package without this "Integration"?  It's buggy (https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/1196216), and I don't want to see it coming back when I upgrade thunderbird.  Apart from a different module distribution, is there another tidy way to make sure it doesn't get reinstalled?

Comment: @mc0e I believe there are packages from Ubuntuzilla that _may not_ have the extension. Otherwise you can download Thunderbird directly from Mozilla and run a local installation.